# Validation fails if redirect after save is anywhere other than the saved object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to make it so that when a user signs up (i.e: a new user is created) it will redirect them to the tutorial. However, when a user signs up it will give an error message saying that the username and email must be unique (even if they are) and render the 'new' page again.

This works fine if I redirect to `@user` instead.

This is my controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
       if @user.save
         login(@user)
         format.html { redirect_to "static/tutorial", success: 'Congratulations on starting your journey!' }
         format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
       else
         format.html { render action: "new" }
         format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end
```

And these are the relevant lines in User.rb:

```
validates_confirmation_of :plain_password
validates_presence_of :name, :username, :email
validates_presence_of :plain_password, :on => :create
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :username
```

Comment: You should think about refactoring your code. There's no reason why you need to perform conditional logic within the `respond_to` block as you currently are.

Comment: @zeantsoi That's the code the rails generator builds, and is pretty sensible when you think about it. There's no reason *not* to put conditional logic in the `respond_to` block.

Answer (score 0):

When I see that I am quite scared

```
validates_presence_of :plain_password, :on => :create
```

Are you saving unencrypted password in your database ?

Regarding your issue you may want to consider using `respond_to` / `respond_with`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # set sessions
    end

    respond_with @user, location: 'static/tutorial'
  end
end
```

Read this blog post http://bendyworks.com/geekville/tutorials/2012/6/respond-with-an-explanation

Comment: Ahahaha, no.. plain_password is an attr_accessor which then gets encrypted to a field in the database called password. It should really be called hashed_password in the database but I'd already called it password, so I didn't bother changing it. Thanks for your concern though!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - partly.

I needed to add a route to the tutorial in my routes file:

```
match "tutorial" => "static#tutorial"
```

And then redirect to that instead of a string:

```
format.html { redirect_to tutorial_path, success: 'Congratulations on starting your journey!' }
```

There is probably a full explanation to the theory behind this but I'll leave that for someone else to answer. This is how I solved it.

Comment: Well yes, you need to define in the route files every accessible path of your application. I suggest using the `get` syntax. Read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Comment: All pages in the `static` controller are available for get requests anyway, with `match 'static/:action', :controller => "static"`